# Adding a div element after and before by jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to ask a stupid question about jQuery. If I have:

```
<ul>
  <li class="ft">
   <ul class="sub"><li></li></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want if become:

```
<ul>
  <li class="ft">
   <div class="hello"><ul class="sub"><li></li></ul></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I add div class="hello" by jQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use `wrap()`

```
$('.sub').wrap('<div class="hello" />');
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

---

as a sidenote: use  `$('.sub')` instead of  `$('ul.sub')` since is more efficient. See http://jsperf.com/jquery-class-vs-element-class

[image]

Comment: Youll get a slight performance increase by changing your selector to `$('ul.sub')`

Comment: @Sam have you done some tests about it? my test say that `.sub` is faster than `ul.sub`

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Yes, on the JavaScript application I work on we get a performance benefit of a few milliseconds. It is a bit of a micro-optimisation but over large front end apps it can make a noticeable difference in performance.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan your jsperf is wrong as you are not cleaning element after wrap it, so second loop will rewrap already wrapped elements making it slower each time a little more

Comment: More accurate jsperf here, you'll see performance are quite the same: http://jsperf.com/jquery-class-vs-element-class/2

Answer (score 2):

`$('.sub').wrap('<div class="hello" />');`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ul.sub').wrap('<div class="hello">');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li.ft').html('<div class="hello">'+$('li.ft').html()+'</div>');
```

Comment: Using that, you'll lose associated data as handlers if any

Answer (score 0):

Use prepend

```
$('.ft').prepend('<div class="hello"><ul class="sub"><li></li></ul></div>');
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways you can achieve this in jquery. Some of them involves you using DOM traversal to reach the element just before you want to add the  and use jquery to add it...jquery has extensive support for this kind of parent,child, sibbling etc traversal...

But the simplest way is to manually add the  element in your html markup and the use jquery to add the class attribute programmatically...

so in your jquery you can simply dosomething like:

jquery("#someid").addclass("hello");

Hope this helps...:)

Answer (score -3):

```
$('li.ft').find('div').addClass('hello');
```

Comment: Not what the question was. The `div` had to be created.